# Awarding bounty to multiple answers

Tags: support, bounty

Can a bounty be awarded to multiple answers?

I have a question that has a number of correct answers, but from slightly different perspectives, so I'd like to give each some of the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

One cannot award one bounty to multiple answers.

One could however place several bounties, one after another, and award each to a different answer. However, one needs to double the amount of the bounty each time, up to 500. It seems this thus will not really be an option in the short-run in your case.

Furthermore, in case  an automatic awarding of the bounty happens it would also be split among tied answers. However, before that the global amount would be reduce  by a factor of two. You should thus also rather not try to exploit this.

Comment: This seems a bit restrictive.

Comment: Possibly. But, others think allowing to split would be unfair. See for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users for discussion. (Personally I have no specific opinion; I just report the situation "as is.")

Comment: You call them as you see them? You could be a whale biologist!